# How to use a .DEF file to erase stdcall '_' decoration?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker

I have an x86 DLL project in Visual Studio Express 2012 that exports a number of `__stdcall` functions. In x86, the MS linker tags each function name with an underscore prefix and a suffix consisting of an `@`-sign followed by a number indicating the number of argument bytes the function pops from the stack when it returns.

e.g. My function declarations are written in C (OK, C++ with `extern "C"`) and the are being mapped to exported symbol names like so:

- `__declspec(dllexport) int32_t __stdcall f()` → `_f@0`
- `__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall g(int64_t)` → `_g@8`

I need to get rid of this decoration so I am only exporting `f`, `g`, and so on.

There are already questions on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4550294/1911388) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4550294/1911388) and the answers explain [you need to use a .DEF file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which you pass to the linker via the `/DEF` switch.

So I made myself a .DEF file which looks like this:

```
EXPORTS
    _f@0  = f
    _g@8  = g
    ...
```

This is working, but only *partially*! In particular, the exported names have changed from `_f@0` → `_f`, `_g@8` → `_g`, and so on. So the '@#' decoration is gone but the leading underscore remains.

How do I get rid of the leading underscore!?

Comment: You got it backwards, it should be f = _f@0

Comment: I'm embarassed but also very happy! That fixed the problem, so thanks a ton for commenting, @Hans Passant.

Comment: You don't even need the `= _f@0` part. The linker will figure that out from the `f`.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen... If I remember I will strip the redundant RHS out.